# C++ implementation of IEEE 1609.2 standard

Tags: library, c++, cryptography

I am looking for a C++ implementation of IEEE 1609.2 standard.

> This standard defines secure message formats and processing for use by Wireless Access in Vehicular Environments (WAVE) devices, including methods to secure WAVE management messages and methods to secure application messages. It also describes administrative functions necessary to support the core security functions.

I have found a Java implementation of this standard [here](https://github.com/pvendil/c2c-common), but nothing in C++.

Does anyone know a library similar to the one linked above?

Comment: Your question may light more bulbs if you explain what the IEEE 1609.2 standard is (add a link; give its alternative names).

Answer (score 0):

My company, OnBoard Security, makes a commercial implementation of 1609.2 called Aerolink: https://www.qualcomm.com/products/features/aerolink-security

(I also wrote the standard :-) )

Comment: This site can’t be reached @William

Comment: We were acquired by Qualcomm in March 2019. The updated version of the page is https://www.qualcomm.com/products/features/aerolink-security.